# why can not I built ny project in unity 2019.1.9 for android?

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine

I have these Errors for a month and I can not build for android device
I when build an empty project for an android device so it is ok and built it but I have a problem for this project what do I do? and what are the problems?

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Users\shahin2002.gradle\wrapper\dists\New folder\gradle-5.1.1-all\97z1ksx6lirer3kbvdnh7jtjg\gradle-5.1.1\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx9096m" "bundleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.

> 1 exception was raised by workers:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.BuildConfig found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
> Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.IUnityAdsListener found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
> Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
> Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds$FinishState found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
> Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds$PlacementState found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
> Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.UnityAds$UnityAdsError found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
> Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.mediation.IUnityAdsExtendedListener found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
> Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.metadata.InAppPurchaseMetaData found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
> Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.metadata.MediationMetaData found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
> Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.metadata.MetaData found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)
> Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.metadata.PlayerMetaData found in modules classes.jar (:UnityAds:) and classes.jar (:unity-ads:)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 58s
]
stdout[

> Configure project :
> Observed package id 'build-tools;26.0.0-rc2' in inconsistent location 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\26.0.0-preview' (Expected 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\26.0.0-rc2')
> Observed package id 'platforms;android-23' in inconsistent location 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-6.0' (Expected 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-23')
> Observed package id 'system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86_64' in inconsistent location 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\temp\SystemImagePackage.old04' (Expected 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86_64')
> Already observed package id 'system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86_64' in 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86_64'. Skipping duplicate at 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\temp\SystemImagePackage.old04'
> Observed package id 'system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86_64' in inconsistent location 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\temp\SystemImagePackage.old06' (Expected 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-26\google_apis\x86_64')
> Already observed package id 'system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86_64' in 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-26\google_apis\x86_64'. Skipping duplicate at 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\temp\SystemImagePackage.old06'
> Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools-25 for  manager' (Expected 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools')
> Already observed package id 'tools' in 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools-25 for  manager'
> Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools-Copy (2)' (Expected 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools')
> Already observed package id 'tools' in 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools-Copy (2)'
> Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools1-4-2020' (Expected 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools')
> Already observed package id 'tools' in 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools1-4-2020'
> Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools2' (Expected 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools')
> Already observed package id 'tools' in 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools2'
> Observed package id 'build-tools;26.0.0-rc2' in inconsistent location 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\26.0.0-preview' (Expected 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\26.0.0-rc2')
> Observed package id 'platforms;android-23' in inconsistent location 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-6.0' (Expected 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-23')
> Observed package id 'system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86_64' in inconsistent location 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\temp\SystemImagePackage.old04' (Expected 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86_64')
> Already observed package id 'system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86_64' in 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86_64'. Skipping duplicate at 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\temp\SystemImagePackage.old04'
> Observed package id 'system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86_64' in inconsistent location 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\temp\SystemImagePackage.old06' (Expected 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-26\google_apis\x86_64')
> Already observed package id 'system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86_64' in 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-26\google_apis\x86_64'. Skipping duplicate at 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\temp\SystemImagePackage.old06'
> Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools-25 for  manager' (Expected 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools')
> Already observed package id 'tools' in 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools-25 for  manager'
> Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools-Copy (2)' (Expected 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools')
> Already observed package id 'tools' in 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools-Copy (2)'
> Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools1-4-2020' (Expected 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools')
> Already observed package id 'tools' in 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools1-4-2020'
> Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools2' (Expected 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools')
> Already observed package id 'tools' in 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'f:\files\pc\Video\artoon\Android\android-sdk\tools2'

> Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unity-android-resources:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unity-android-resources:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unity-android-resources:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :unity-android-resources:processReleaseManifest
> Task :preReleaseBuild
> Task :unity-android-resources:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :generateReleaseResValues
> Task :generateReleaseResources
> Task :unity-android-resources:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unity-android-resources:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unity-android-resources:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unity-android-resources:packageReleaseResources
> Task :mergeReleaseResources
> Task :checkReleaseManifest
> Task :createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :mainApkListPersistenceRelease
> Task :processReleaseManifest
> Task :bundleReleaseResources
> Task :mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :compileReleaseShaders
> Task :generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unity-android-resources:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unity-android-resources:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unity-android-resources:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unity-android-resources:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED
> 19 actionable tasks: 19 executed
> ]
> exit code: 1
> UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <1a10f9035b6b403994c99e5b653643c6>:0)
> UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <1a10f9035b6b403994c99e5b653643c6>:0)
> UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <1a10f9035b6b403994c99e5b653643c6>:0)
> UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <1a10f9035b6b403994c99e5b653643c6>:0) UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <1a10f9035b6b403994c99e5b653643c6>:0)
> Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
> UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <1a10f9035b6b403994c99e5b653643c6>:0)
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <1a10f9035b6b403994c99e5b653643c6>:0)
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <1a10f9035b6b403994c99e5b653643c6>:0)
> Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <1a10f9035b6b403994c99e5b653643c6>:0)
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <1a10f9035b6b403994c99e5b653643c6>:0)
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <1a10f9035b6b403994c99e5b653643c6>:0)
> UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <1a10f9035b6b403994c99e5b653643c6>:0)
> UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:281)
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVldN.png)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling you that both classes.jar (inside default Unity) and classes.jar (inside your ads plugin) contains at least one class that is exactly the same.

There are two solutions, depending if you're the owner (or have the source code) of the plugin, or not.

**If you have ads plugin code**, open it and force AndroidStudio to not implement classes.jar, just compile them.

**If you don't have plugin code**, change plugin .aar file extension to ".rar" or ".zip" and open it. Pick classes.jar and AndroidManifest.xml files and drop it on your Unity/Plugins/Android directory.

Comment: Thanks for answer but , I have not android astudio, this is unity project and I searched on folder project and did not classes.jar .,but i have 2 AndroidManifest.xml files that are correctly, what do I do?

Comment: Clases.jar are located inside your .jar/.aar plugins. Locate those plugins and do what my answer suggest on "if you don't have plugin code"